# TinyMCE editor height in webkit ( autoresize plugin )

Tags: jquery, tinymce, text-editor

I'm using the TinyMCE script on my page. I have several editors on the page and everything's working fine aside from the height of the actual text container in webkit based browsers. Basically the height is set to 34 pixels and the text container only expands ( to its supposed height ) when I'm focusing it and press any of the keys.

Apparently there was an issue with the heights on [webkit before](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4620), but I still found it buggy.

Does anybody know how to get the text containers heights after the page's been loaded on webkit ( basically it should behave as it does under Firefox )?

PS: I'm using version 3.5b1

Thanks!

Comment: 3.5b1 - the naming looks like a beta version, please use the latest stable release

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem with Chrome, tinyMCE 3.5.6 and the autoresize plugin. What helped was manually calling the resize plugin in the [`init_instance_callback`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:init_instance_callback).

You can find an example in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12382834/1062304) to a similiar question.