# tinymce autoresize with chrome when readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, tinymce

Hi guys i tried the full day, but i did not get it.

I use the tinymce editor and in all browsers it works fine, except in **** chrome. I use the autoresize in readonly mode and i always have the problem that in chrome the editor iframe is ~20px to small, so that often text is missing.

I am not the jquery or javascript crack and did not find a solution for it.
There is a row where it is setting the style `h.setStyle(h.get(a.id + "_ifr"), "height", k + "px");` but when i would add +20 i have the problem that in editor mode it always adds 20 px when keydown. So not a solution.

Add some pixeld by css? But how do i access the iframe element?
Maybe someone of you have an idea what i can do here to add there extra pixels.

**EDIT**

Ok seems no one has interest to help so i do it with a workaround. In the plugin file i do the following, maybe it helps people, having the same problem:

```
if (tinymce.isWebKit && tinymce.activeEditor.settings.readonly == true) {
```

Then you can add some extra pixels, in my case 20px. Maybe there are much better solutions, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similiar problem with Chrome, tinyMCE 3.5.6 and the autoresize plugin. What helped was manually calling the resize plugin in the [`init_instance_callback`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainit_instance_callback). I'm calling tinyMCE (jQuery version) like this now when the window is loaded:

```
$('.tinymce').tinymce({
  theme : 'advanced',
  plugins : 'autoresize',
  width: '100%',
  height: 400,
  autoresize_min_height: 400,
  autoresize_max_height: 800,
  init_instance_callback: function (inst) { inst.execCommand('mceAutoResize'); }
});
```